# How can I close all AudioContexts created within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web-audio-api

I'm developing a web app, where the user can write Web Audio code and get a preview of their code within an iframe. Whenever an input textarea is changed, the iframe `contentDocument` is updated.

The problem is that when a user creates an `AudioContext`, a new context is created on top of the old one. This quickly leads to too many ACs being created, and also leaves any of the previous ones playing.

I need a way of doing something like

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

for (ac in iframe.contentWindow.audioContexts) {
    ac.close();
}

iframe.contentDocument.open();
iframe.contentDocument.write("//some new js/html code here");
```

Which is just concept code and obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to effectively 'reload' all the audio content created within the iframe, just like it reloads when a standard webpage is reloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to reload all AudioContexts in an iframe

Alright, I found a way which may not be optimal for everyone, but nevertheless does work.

Basically, you need to simulate reloading the website in your iframe.

This can be done in a number of ways, for instance:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

iframe.onload = function() {
    iframe.contentDocument.open();
    iframe.contentDocument.write("//some new js/html code here");
    iframe.contentDocument.close();
}
// src can be an empty string if you're not loading anything into it by default
iframe.src = your_iframe_src || "";
```

Now, this isn't super fast, it did introduce a bit of lag in my app, but that can be solved by using a separate rendering/validation loop.